# Add summary row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am generating data-set by `UNION` three data-sets. Then I want to add a `summary` row at the end of the data-set for just one column.

**Data:**

```
id  uid type    seen
1   20  A       1
2   20  B       1
3   20  C       1
4   6   A       1
5   1   A       1
6   3   A       0
7   6   A       0
8   1   B       0
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    (SELECT
            type,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uid) AS users,
            COUNT(type) AS typeCount,
            MIN(seen) as seen
    FROM `test2`
    WHERE type = 'A'
    GROUP BY type)

    UNION

    (SELECT
            type,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uid) AS users,
            COUNT(type) AS typeCount,
            MIN(seen) as seen
    FROM `test2`
    WHERE type = 'B'
    GROUP BY type)

    UNION

    (SELECT
            type,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uid) AS users,
            COUNT(type) AS typeCount,
            MIN(seen) as seen
    FROM `test2`
    WHERE type = 'C'
    GROUP BY type)
) as result
```

**Query Results:**

```
id  uid         type    seen
A   20,6,1,3    5       0
B   20,1        2       0
C   20          1       1
```

**Expected Results:**

```
id      uid         type    seen
A       20,6,1,3    5       0
B       20,1        2       0
C       20          1       1
total                       2      -- counting `0` here
```

**PS:** I know the query can be simplified by just using `GROUP BY` but it is not the real scenario, it is just a minimal explanation of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you need `UNION` not `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Yes, I don't want duplication

Comment: For group by we can do some rollup  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html However the query you had in question could be much simplified provided you outline more information and logic what you are after. Perhaps a fiddle with some proper sample data and expected result into the question.

Comment: I know it can be simplified, but as I mentioned it is just a minimal example, real query is much more complex than this. I create a fiddle.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5dc4a/3/0

Comment: Where does 'B' come from?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `ROLLUP` on your query..just leave your sub query as is right know then apply `GROUP BY` on them

```
SELECT type, MIN(users) users, MIN(typeCount) typeCount, MIN(seen) seen, IF(seen=0,1,0) zero_seen FROM
(

    --  previous sub query

) as result
GROUP BY type WITH ROLLUP
```

EDIT:
`ROLLUP` only do **sum** or calculate grand total, to do **count** `IF(seen=0,1,0) zero_seen` added to **count** `0` seen..

Comment: But I want to count only `0`. I can use rollup too, Can you apply rollup on this query?